# How to print! an Option<Box<struct>>?

Tags: rust

I am trying to print an `Option<Box<MyStruct>>`, but I get a compile error when trying to implement `Display for Option<Box<MyStruct>>`.

```
use std::fmt;

fn main() {
    let maybe_my_struct: Option<Box<MyStruct>> = Some(Box::new(MyStruct{foo:42}));
    println!("{}", maybe_my_struct);
}

struct MyStruct {
    foo: i32,
}

impl fmt::Display for Option<Box<MyStruct>> {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Some(MyStruct) => write!(formatter, "{}", self.foo),
            None => write!(formatter, "No struct"),
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is :

```
error: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate; 
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types [E0117]
```

I have tried aliasing the `Option` type, and instead implementing `Display for MyOption<Box<MyStruct>>`, but that gives the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see, you can't implement a trait you didn't write for a type you didn't write.  This is part of what's known as "coherence" and exists to prevent really weird things like linking against a library suddenly causing unrelated parts of your program to change behaviour.

Aliasing `Option` to `MyOption` doesn't work *either* because, as you say, it's an *alias*.  That is, it's just another name for the same thing, it's not an actual, different type.

Now, if you write a *wrapper* around `Option` like so:

```rust
struct MyOption<T>(Option<T>);
```

*then* `MyOption` will be a new, distinct type that you can implement a trait for.  Of course, you'll want to write methods to wrap and unwrap the actual `Option` you're storing.

... But this is all rather irrelevant since you *could also* just derive `Debug` for your struct and use that.

```rust
fn main() {
    let maybe_my_struct: Option<Box<MyStruct>> = Some(Box::new(MyStruct{foo:42}));
    println!("{:?}", Some(maybe_my_struct));
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    foo: i32,
}
```

Or, if you really want the custom display logic for the `Option<Box<MyStruct>>` combination, you can use a marker value (this same approach is used by `Path` in the standard library, incidentally).  Like so:

```rust
use std::fmt;

fn main() {
    let maybe_my_struct: Option<Box<MyStruct>> = Some(Box::new(MyStruct{foo:42}));
    println!("{:?}", maybe_my_struct);

    // Instead of displaying directly, display via a custom marker.
    println!("{}", maybe_my_struct.display());
    println!("{}", None::<Box<MyStruct>>.display());
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    foo: i32,
}

// This is the marker we'll use to define our custom Display impl.
struct MmsDisplay<'a>(&'a Option<Box<MyStruct>>);

// This trait lets us extend Option<Box<MyStruct>> with a new method.
trait CustomMmsDisplay {
    fn display<'a>(&'a self) -> MmsDisplay<'a>;
}

impl CustomMmsDisplay for Option<Box<MyStruct>> {
    fn display<'a>(&'a self) -> MmsDisplay<'a> {
        MmsDisplay(self)
    }
}

// And here's the display logic.
impl<'a> fmt::Display for MmsDisplay<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self.0 {
            Some(ref ms) => write!(formatter, "{}", ms.foo),
            None => write!(formatter, "No struct"),
        }
    }
}
```